# Find the javascript error that I'm getting in phonegap on android

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova, error-handling

I have a phonegap application that is throwing a javascript error. I have had the HTML page open in a browser on the desktop and it works fine there without any error. When I load it in the android emulator the window.onerror event is getting fired, but I can't see any useful information in the error object to see where it's coming from. I have this to try to get more out of the error object:

```
window.onerror = function(e){
    for(var i in e){
        console.log("window.onerror ::" + i + ' = ' + e[i]);
    }
};
```

But I don't even see a 'message' property. Here's the output:

```
window.onerror ::undefined
window.onerror ::eventPhase = 3
window.onerror ::currentTarget = [object DOMWindow]
window.onerror ::cancelable = false
window.onerror ::target = [object HTMLScriptElement]
window.onerror ::bubbles = true
window.onerror ::type = error
window.onerror ::cancelBubble = false
window.onerror ::clipboardData = undefined
window.onerror ::srcElement = [object HTMLScriptElement]
window.onerror ::defaultPrevented = false
window.onerror ::timeStamp = 1330975112077
window.onerror ::returnValue = true
window.onerror ::stopPropagation = function stopPropagation() { [native code] }
window.onerror ::preventDefault = function preventDefault() { [native code] }
window.onerror ::initEvent = function initEvent() { [native code] }
window.onerror ::stopImmediatePropagation = function stopImmediatePropagation() { [native code] }
window.onerror ::CAPTURING_PHASE = 1
window.onerror ::AT_TARGET = 2
window.onerror ::BUBBLING_PHASE = 3
window.onerror ::MOUSEDOWN = 1
window.onerror ::MOUSEUP = 2
window.onerror ::MOUSEOVER = 4
window.onerror ::MOUSEOUT = 8
window.onerror ::MOUSEMOVE = 16
window.onerror ::MOUSEDRAG = 32
window.onerror ::CLICK = 64
window.onerror ::DBLCLICK = 128
window.onerror ::KEYDOWN = 256
window.onerror ::KEYUP = 512
window.onerror ::KEYPRESS = 1024
window.onerror ::DRAGDROP = 2048
window.onerror ::FOCUS = 4096
window.onerror ::BLUR = 8192
window.onerror ::SELECT = 16384
window.onerror ::CHANGE = 32768
```

What else can I do to find the problem?

Comment: Well you can debug the code...?

Comment: I don't know, can I? I just installed eclipse - I've never used it or any other java tool before. Can you set a breakpoint in a javascript class with it or set it to auto break on any javascript exception?

Comment: It has been a while since I used eclipse, don't know... but in VS you can. =)

Comment: That'd be nice if I could use VS, but my laptop is just old enough that I can't get a video driver that supports the Windows Phone 7 emulator. There's not a way to attach VS to the android emulator, is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you can install Chrome for android and remote debug/analyze your application in the same way you would do with regular chrome: 
http://code.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging.html

To install Chrome in the emulator:

- Download the apk (from here for example: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1515900)
- Start your emulator running the appropriate version of android (4.0 for this specific apk)
- execute adb install chrome.apk

it may take a while to install. Then follow the instructions to remote debug your web application

Comment: I don't have the application deployed to a mobile device, just to the android emulator launched from eclipse. Does this apply to me?

Comment: Looks promising. I'll have to try it out.

Comment: btw I've seen people having problems with Chrome to work in the emulator, make sure you have the latest API updates installed, it would be probably best to try it on a real device if you have one available

Comment: This does not apply to Phonegap as far as I'm aware. According to that link your WebView has to be setup in a certain way to enable debugging and you must be using KitKat.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing out as the error handler is actually passed multiple arguments, so you need to log those too.

For example,

```
window.onerror = function(e,f,g){
   console.log("window.onerror ", e, f, g);
};
```